# Counting vowels and consonants in a file (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, lowercase

I need to make a program that will read a text file and print how many vowels and consonants there are. I make a text file to test and the only thing in it is "This is a test". However the output it always:

Enter the file to check: test.txt

The number of Vowels is:  1

The number of consonants is:  0

```
fileName = input("Enter the file to check: ").strip()

infile = open(fileName, "r")


vowels = set("A E I O U a e i o u")
cons = set("b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x y z B C D F G H J K L M N P Q R S T V W X Y Z")

text = infile.read().split()


countV = 0
for V in text:
    if V in vowels:
        countV += 1

countC = 0
for C in text:
    if C in cons:
        countC += 1

print("The number of Vowels is: ",countV,"\nThe number of consonants is: ",countC)
```

If there is a better way to enter the values for vowels and cons I would also like to know, as I get an error when I try to user .lower() to convert everything in the file to lower case.....

Comment: Because you count spaces as well??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `set("A E I O U a e i o u")` will result in `{' ', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}`. If you'll notice, the space is also considered. You'll need to remove the spaces between the letters.
2. `infile.read().split()` will split based on whitespace so you get a *list of words*. You then proceed to iterate over the *words*, and try a membership comparison between the *words* and the *letters*. This will not work out for you.
3. You don't need to iterate twice. Once is enough.

---

Here's a cleaned up version of your code.

```
vowels = set("AEIOUaeiou")
cons = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ")

countV = 0
countC = 0
for c in infile.read():
    if c in vowels:
        countV += 1
    elif c in cons:
        countC += 1
```

---

As an improvement, consider the use of `collections.Counter`. It does the counting for you, and you just sum up the counts.

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(infile.read())

countV = sum(c[k] for k in c if k in vowels)
countC = sum(c[k] for k in c if k in cons)
```

Comment: Thank you @COLDSPEED this helped. I did it slightly different but getting rid of the .split() and removing the spaces was a big help. I thought that sets don't repeat themselves though? So doesn't that mean that it would count the spaces too rather than showing 0 as a result?

Comment: @EvanH It counts the spaces once, but they are still counted. You will have spaces erroneously counted as both vowels and characters unless you removed them.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Got it. Thank you very much for the help and quick response!

Answer (score 0):

If the input file `fileName` contains characters different than vowels and consonants like `. , \n` a solution is to use `re.split()` and `re.sub()` instead of the method `str.split()`:

```
import re
text = re.split("\s+", re.sub("[.,\n+]", " ", infile.read()))
```

The expresion `re.sub("[.,\n+]", " ", infile.read())` will substitute the characters `. , \n` with whitespaces. Then the expresion `re.split("\s+", re.sub("[.,\n+]", " ", infile.read())` will split the 'clean' `infile.read()` text using as criteria one of more repetition of whitespace characters

Answer (score 0):

```
fileName = input("Enter the file to check: ").strip()

infile = open(fileName, "r")
  
vowels = set("A E I O U a e i o u")
cons = set("b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x y z B C D F G H J K L M N P Q R S T V W X Y Z")

text = infile.read().split()
    
countV = 0
for V in text:
    if V in vowels:
        countV += 1

countC = 0
for C in text:
    if C in cons:
        countC += 1

print("The number of Vowels is: ", countV, "\nThe number of consonants is: ", countC)
```